# IOS, UIWebview,

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebviewdelegate

`Webview` delegate `shouldstartloadwithrequest` recieves url from HTML and when i check the request everything is been converted to small letters:

```
- (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType {
    // Only do something if a link has been clicked
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSString *link = [[request URL] absoluteString];
        if ([link hasPrefix:@"playSound:"]) {
            [PlayAudio playAudio: [link substringFromIndex:10]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The line that make the problem is

```
NSString *link = [[request URL] absoluteString];
```

Before I got an unmodified copy of the clicked link. In iOS3 and iOS4 it is still the same. But on iOS5 it is converted to lowercase only. The next Line

```
if ([link hasPrefix:@"playSound:"]) {
```

never becomes true. So I had to change the code to

```
- (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType {
    // Only do something if a link has been clicked
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSString *link = [[[request URL] absoluteString] lowercaseString];
        if ([link hasPrefix:@"playsound:"]) {
            [PlayAudio playAudio: [link substringFromIndex:10]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Soooo... what's the question?

Comment: Exactly .. wat's it ??

Comment: -1 for no actual question. Will remove if a question is asked.

Comment: the question, inelegantly, is just why did the scheme get converted to lowercase and what can he do about it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a change made as part of the upgrade to safari in iOS 5 and is consistent with the spec for URL's.  The URL scheme will always be converted to lower case.

(I had to fix a lot of code because of this change)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([link hasPrefix:@"playsound:"] ||[link hasPrefix:@"playSound:"] )
{
    [PlayAudio playAudio: [link substringFromIndex:10]];
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that im getting the encoded value in the request field. As i recieve everything in small i cant decode it. When i decode it im getting as nil..